# Can't get values from rows/cells in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying get values from a GridView using the following code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in this.dgvEstudios.Rows)
{
    var xy = row.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Always get a an empty string (`""`) as the value returned from `.Text`, why does this happen? I have set `EnableViewState` to `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell might have controls inside it (e.g. LiteralControl or an HyperLink). This is what you should be looking for.

`row.Cells[1].Controls`  collection, you should look for.

Comment: this works! but specifing the index from ControlsCollection like this:
row.Cells[1].Controls[1];

this is a normal behavior?

Answer (score 4):

If there are controls in each cell you will need to get the value like this:

```
Label lblEmailAddress = GridView.Rows[e.CommandArgument].FindControl("lblEmailAddress");
string Email = lblEmailAddress.Text;
```

in that case it it the control in the cell that has the value not the cell iteslf.

Answer (score 1):

it could depend on many things..  Where is this code fired in relation to when the GridView is populated (Databind() called)?

Without  any context, its hard to say what else it could be.

Comment: Im using RowDataBound for play with data inside GridView, by the way I will test the first answer, but what about ViewState?