# getting the value of the boundfield in a gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have encountered something strange. 
I wanted to have the value of my gridview boundfield so I did this.

```
SelectedID = objGridView.Rows(0).Cells(4).Text.ToString
```

At first this seemed to work. I played around a little created a hyperlinkfield wanted to get that value but got an empty string. After some looking around it turned out I could not get it as easily as I could with a boundtextfield.  No problem.

But here comes my problem , now all of a sudden my line of code to retrieve the value from the selectedId does not work anymore ( at least I'm getting empty strings back ).

I've build and rebuild my gridview but to no avail. 
I'm flabbergasted and don't get it why it doesn't work anymore. 
Hence my question. 
Does anyone have an idea what's happening or have a solution to this problem.

edit:
I'm seeing this in my item value
"In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user"

Comment: In case anyone reads this, I have this exact problem. I use the same code to retrieve data from a BoundField, and get nothing but empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you dont use the datagridview.

I started with GridView as well but after changing the control type it's really easy to get those values  e.g:

```
SelectedID = dgvExample.CurrentRow.Cells("Columname/Index").Value
```

[dgv compared with gv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171628.aspx)

Comment: This is an old post, but for clarity, DataGridView is a Windows desktop form. Gridview is for web sites. They are very different and not compatible in the opposite environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437137/cant-get-values-from-rows-cells-in-gridview)

An other one (which was the reason of my problem) could be that the BoundFields are set to Visible = false. Invisible Bound fields are... not bound.

A simple workaround is to make it invisible in CSS instead.

Code behind :

```
gvColumn.ItemStyle.CssClass = "className"
```

CSS :

```
.className { display:none; }
```