# how to get value of row in gridview and display in textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get value of row in `Gridview` and display in `Textbox`?

Don't work this code. And I don't want to use this code:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e) {
        LinkButton lnkButton = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) lnkButton.NamingContainer;
        lblSender.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        lblSubject.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;
        txtReadMsg.Text = row.Cells[6].Text;
```

Comment: What grid event are you doing that in?

Comment: protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
      
    }

Comment: You will be getting lots of down votes asking the question that way. Elaborate please, nobody can help you if you don´t explain properly. What does not works? Does the row assignment works properly?

Comment: What you need, on a row button click to display data?

Comment: Show us the aspx markup.

Comment: actually, I want to display row of GridView in Text Box

Comment: What objects are in the cells of your GridView? You may want to use FindControl to do what you want, but I'm not sure. Something like TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)myGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBoxInGridView"); then lblSender.Text = myTextBox.Text;

Comment: @Melanie - I'd mark this as the actual answer. I'm assuming the OP is databinding to the gridview, and then using labels, literals, or textboxes to display the information... although it's definitely hard to give a specific answer to a non-specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your GridView's cells don't have controls inside it.

maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437137/cant-get-values-from-rows-cells-in-gridview) helps you

Answer (score 0):

To get the row, do:

```
var row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
```

And then the rest of the code should work for you. You can then remove the first two lines.  Also, note Text only works if you are using BoundColumn column definitions; it won't work if you are using a different type of column.

If you are getting a different error, then it's related to something else; please add a comment and we can help work through it.